# API request saying not found

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

Trying to get product detail from django rest framework. However whenever try:

```
  baseurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
  httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllProducts(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl +'/product/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders})
  }
  getProductDetails(slug: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseurl}/product/${slug}/`, {headers: this.httpHeaders})
  }
```

i get an error saying:

```
Not Found: /product/[object Object]/
[20/Oct/2021 21:54:32] "GET /product/[object%20Object]/ HTTP/1.1" 404 23
```

django backend views:

```
class Product(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = "slug"
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

django url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.ProductListView.as_view(), name="product"),
    path("<slug>/", views.Product.as_view(), name="product_detail"),
]
```

Comment: this is more of a backend issue, your server is returning a 404, not found. means it cannot account for that endpoint. Could be with your encoded URI.

Comment: @PouyaAtaei ah ok ok. I made an edit to the code with a few of the backend codes

Comment: Looks like an issue in your `getProductDetails`. `${slug}` is returning `[object Object]`. Is slug really a string?

Comment: @BrianDestura well it should be a string, however it is returning an object

Answer (score 1):

In your **Django**'s **url.py** you should have something. like:

```
path('api/product/', some_view),
path('api/product/<slug>', some_other_view),
```

Notice that **api** prefix.

Don't provide **baseURL** as full url, instead, create a proxy configuration file **src/proxy.conf.json** like the following:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

notice that prefix **api** - this is essential - can be something else, but it's the contract your proxy uses.

then update your **angular.json**:

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
           "browserTarget": "yourapp:build",
           "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "yourapp:build:production",
          "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "yourapp:build:development",
          "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

Now if you use **ng serve** you can run:

```
ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json
```

And lastly, all you need in your **Angular** service as base url is:

```
this.baseurl =  '/api/product';
```

Now you can call any of your service **http** methods as **Angular** knows your server's configuration from proxy and **Django** provides paths with same prefix.
Remember that **Django** requires **POST** requests to use forward slash so you might need to configure `APPEND_SLASH` in your **settings.py** as per [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash)

Comment: thanks man! I see the use of this. However still getting the [object%20Object] error.

Comment: try ```console.log(JSON.stringify(error))``` - send some payload back and see what returns back in inspector or use Postman to get explicit payload back. 200 is successful status, it's possible that your call is not parsed properly.

Comment: did and getting a --- Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}

Comment: If in inpector's **Network** tab you see status 200 that should be the problem with what your actual endpoint returns but not with endpoint being rejected by **Angular** anymore. Also you're dealing with observable here, so you have to subscribe to it to get result - [Rrxj Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)